# Alphanumeric sorting without any pattern on the strings

Tags: postgresql, sorting, alphanumeric

- BIB BS 105
- BIB BM 106
- B BP 3.5
- BIB BS 4.2
- BIB BS 1
- BIB 109
- BZ 288

Is there a way using PostgreSQL to sort these into

- B BP 3.5
- BIB 109
- BIB BM 106
- BIB BS 1
- BIB BS 4.2
- BIB BS 105
- BZ 288

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your data is ugly, because sometimes you have 2 values, other times 3.  On top of this, sometimes the second value is text, other times a float.  You should fix your table design here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen
["BS 105", "BM 106", "BP 3.5", "B 4.2", "BS 1", "B 109", "BZ 288"]

How about these?